# Как использовать методы дочернего класса через итератор, который пробегается по списку базового класса?

Tags: c++

Я писал игру, где у меня возникла одна проблема. С ней справится я не смог, поэтому обращаюсь сюда. Дабы вам было понятнее, я написал отдельный код, где тоже возникает эта ошибка (её код, кстати -1073741819).

Вопрос заключается вот в чём:
Как использовать методы дочернего класса через итератор, который пробегается по списку базового класса?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;

};

class B : public A {
public:
    int value;
    B(int value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void func() override {
        cout << value << endl;
    }
};

list<A*> aclass;
list<A*>::iterator IT;

void create(int value) {
    aclass.push_back(&B(value));
}

int main() {
    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
        create(l);
    }

    for (IT = aclass.begin(); IT != aclass.end(); IT++) {
        (*IT)->func();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще, `aclass.push_back(&B(value));` не должно компилироваться. Вы берете адрес временного объекта.

Comment: Как же тогда создавать объекты через функцию? Я слышал, что нужно сохранить на них указатель. Как мне казалось - достаточно закинуть адрес объекта в список

Comment: Сохранение указателя на объект не влияет на то, как долго он существует. Временный `B(value)` существует до конца строки, грубо говоря. Почитайте про `new`, `delete` (и про виртуальные деструкторы заодно).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы почти всё сделали правильно. Проблема есть лишь в том, на что указал [@HolyBlackCat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215103/holyblackcat) – нужно заменить `&B(value)` на `new B(value)` и всё заработает.

Вкратце о том, почему: когда Вы делаете просто `B(value)`, создаётся временный объект класса `B`. Если передать в качестве аргумента сам этот объект, он будет скопирован и сохранён в списке. Но Вы передаёте только лишь указатель. Указатель на временный объект. А временному объекту "всё равно", был на него создан указатель или нет, его дело маленькое, он просуществовал до конца строки и, если не был скопирован, канул в лету. Следовательно, полученный указатель указывает на объект, которого уже нет. Чтобы создать "постоянный" объект и взять на него указатель, используется оператор `new`.